# An app forum for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forum

I'm looking for a forum app for rails 3.
All the forums is for rails2.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[Forem](https://github.com/radar/forem) is a Rails 3.1 engine and it looks pretty legit.

Answer (score 2):

I saw that [rboard](http://github.com/radar/rboard/) is rails3 based, I haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

For a more modern alternative, you could try [Discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse).